# Get URL to current background-image and hand over to <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue i couldn't figure out so far. I googled and searched here, found some answers, but I can't get it to work.

I want to figure out the current background image from css and create a link to download the image.

This is my simplyfied code so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
body.custom-background { background-image: url('http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bg2.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center; background-attachment: scroll; }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var image = body.custom-background.css('background-image').replace(/^url\((.*?)\)$/,     '$1');
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute("href",image);


</script>

<div id="hide">
    <a id="hidepage">hide page</a>
    <a id="showpage" style="display:none;">show page</a>
</div>

<div id="downloadbg">

    <a id="link"><br>Download Background</a>
</div>
```

I am pretty new to programming and I am running out of ideas.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does the produced link look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.custom-background { background-image: url('http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bg2.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center; background-attachment: scroll; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var image = $(".custom-background").css('background-image').replace(/^url\((.*?)\)$/,     '$1');
        $('#link').attr("href", image);

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="custom-background">
    <div id="hide">
        <a id="hidepage">hide page</a>
        <a id="showpage" style="display:none;">show page</a>
    </div>
    <div id="downloadbg">
        <a id="link"><br>Download Background</a>
    </div>
</body>
​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kSCdw/)

To make the link into a donwload, and not just show the image, you will have to do some serverside scripting, setting the headers `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` !

Answer (score 0):

$('body').css('background-image')

That will get your background image value using jquery (if you want that), then you have to set your href in the link (looks like you're doing that).

Following straight javascript as your doing, getting the background image would be:

var image = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]

var bg = image.style.backgroundImage;

That will also get the value you have set it in the link

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to execute your function on DOM ready (can't tell for sure as simplified code) but normally this should work fine.

```
$(function() {
    $('#link').attr('href', $('body.custom-background').css('background-image').replace(/^url\((.*?)\)$/, '$1'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/p93jx/9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

   <style type='text/css'>
      body { background-image: url('http://localhost:8888/wp-   content/uploads/2012/04/bg2.jpg'); 
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      background-position: top center; 
      background-attachment: scroll; }
   </style>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         var image = $('body').css('background-image');
         image.match(/url\((.*?)\)/);
         document.getElementById('link').setAttribute("href",image);
      });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="hide">
      <a id="hidepage">hide page</a>
      <a id="showpage" style="display:none;">show page</a>
   </div>

   <div id="downloadbg">
      <a id="link"><br>Download Background</a>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one, non-jQuery, method:

```
function bgLink(elem, from) {
    if (!elem || !from) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var bgLink = window.getComputedStyle(from, null).backgroundImage,
            url = bgLink.substring(bgLink.indexOf('http:')).replace(')', '');
        elem.href = url;
        elem.innerHTML = url;
    }
}

bgLink(document.getElementById('downloadBG'), document.getElementById('bgElem'));​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ARtEp/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to body, before the entire dom has been loaded. So you should wrap your javascript in a jQuery function: $(function(){ code here!;}); which gives the same result as listening to the jQuery.ready event. Alternatively you can move your javascript code to the bottom of your page.

Something like this should do the job:

```
<head>
  <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ background: url(@{'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bg2.jpg'}); }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            var image = $('body').css('background-image').replace(/^url\((.*?)\)$/,     '$1');;
            $('#link').attr('href', image);
        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="hide">
        <a id="hidepage">hide page</a>
        <a id="showpage" style="display:none;">show page</a>
    </div>

    <div id="downloadbg">
        <a id="link"><br>Download Background</a>
    </div>

</body>
```